# How to check if user entered userid already exists in the firebase through java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried so many ways to check if a user id is already in the firebase but all method are in vain.
Below is my code to check if user id exists but whatever data I enter it does not show the required error.

```
userid = findViewById(R.id.userid);
String userVal = userid.getEditText(). getText().toString();
boolean userquery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").orderByChild("userid").equals(userVal);


    if(userquery) {
        userid.setError("This user name already exists");
        return;
    }
```

Whenever I try to add existing value in the input it accepts the value and overwrites in the database.

Here is the screenshot of my firebase database.

[image]

Comment: used the 2nd method to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code so far only sets up a query. It doesn't actually execute the query, so there's no way it can detect whether the data exists. To [execute a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), you have to [attach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) to it.

So in your case, that could be something like:

```
boolean userquery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").orderByChild("userid").equals(userVal);
userquery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else if (task.getResult().exists()) {
            userid.setError("This user name already exists");
        }
    }
});
```

On older SDK versions the equivalent would be:

```
boolean userquery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").orderByChild("userid").equals(userVal);
userquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            userid.setError("This user name already exists");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is tash in 'tash.getResult()'?

Comment: That was a typo, and should've been `task`. I've fixed the code in my answer, but I also recommend reading up on tasks as there are a pretty basic Android concept: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks

Comment: `userquery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>()` after typing this line I am getting error that **Cannot resolve .get() method**

Comment: Are you on an old SDK by any chance. This method was introduced a few months ago. Before that you could only use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to accomplish the same: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_a_listener

Comment: I am quite new to android studio. Will you tell me how to check for the sdk and how to change its version

Comment: I added an example of doing this with the older method too. Let me know if that works better for you.